# Aloe Vera And Thin Chalk Stick issues

Tags: houseplants, aloe

I’ve had Milo (aloe) and chalk sticks for about the same time, which is about a year. Milo’s leaves are worrying me because they aren’t necessarily browning, but they are not what regular aloe look like. They are thin and somewhat squishy, I know it’s a sign of root rot, but I recently repotted him with more pearlite. He seemed to be doing a little better. I also live in Ohio so light is hard to come by, I have a sunlight for all of my succulents who all seem to be doing alright except for Milo and the chalk sticks. As for the thin chalk sticks, they’re too thin and as pictured, a little wrinkly. I do my try to keep them on a watering schedule of once every two weeks, or two and a half. [image][image][image]

Comment: Did you have a question? Overall both plants look like they have never been outdoors. Aloes especially benefit from a deep pot. It helps the root crown stay dry but allows the fibrous roots reach down deep in search of water - Aloe’s natural habit. How about repotting both of them with fresh soil?